# Sudo command from remote/CI platform does not work

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, sudo

I am able to run sudo command for my user on a linux server.
But when I run the same command from another (Jenkins CI console) to the same Linux server.

it says "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"

My command is like this, 
echo ${somePassword} | sudo -S chown someUser /someFile.war

Comment: One or more of the following could be causing this:
1. The user Jenkins runs as may not have the same sudo privs as your own user.
2. The Jenkins process is actually not connecting with a tty, which sudo legitimately will not allow.

See if you can run 'sudo -l' to verify the Jenkins user has the right access. If you get the same error message, it's more likely the 2nd problem.

Comment: Did you try : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password